# link to website automatically inserting text into textarea

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, textarea

On my website I want to link to a web-app, automatically inserting some text into a textarea.

Is it possible to link to the website doing something like this?

```
www.website.com/#document.getElementById('textarea').value ='inserted text';
```

This bookmarklet is working code, I just want to use a link to the website and somehow get it to run the bookmarklet automatically.

```
javascript:{document.getElementById('textarea').value = 'inserted text'; void(0)}
```

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Executing arbitrary javascript code embedded in a query string would be a seriously large security hole. Don't expect this to work any time soon.

Comment: As others have said, that's not possible. I would pass the text as a URL variable like `website.com?text=abc` and then use JavaScript to put it in the textarea.

Comment: @Mike W That's fair, but why are bookmarklets something we can use? They seem to do the same thing, just in one less step.

Comment: @crclayton: Because the bookmarklet is under the control of the end user, whereas users don't usually look closely at links before clicking, especially not the part toward the end of a long link...

Comment: I'll just use an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On my website I want to link to a web-app, automatically inserting some text into a textarea.

You cannot, unless that web-app provides a means for you to do so (for instance, passing information on a query string or otherwise as part of the URL). You can't create a link that runs JavaScript on the page after loading it, not without the page's cooperation.

---

On the off-chance that the target web-app is also under your control: You could, of course, add a feature to the web-app to do it. If so, be sure you just accept a *value* and don't allow executing arbitrary JavaScript code passed to you on the URL, that would be a Very Bad Idea unless the target page never shows anything user-specific (and probably even if it doesn't).